# Visual Studio - Addin to allow rows of files

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

I am a Delphi Transplant to .Net.  I really like it, but I am missing one thing that I am wondering if there is an addin for.

In Delphi there is an addin (called GExperts) that allows you to make your files show in rows at the top of your code window (rather than just one row that only shows as much as can fit).

Is there something like this for Visual Studio?  (If not does this sound like a feasible addin for a first time addin writer (ie me) to write?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [TabsStudio](http://www.tabsstudio.com/), which does this and some other things. It's not free (34$).